# iPhone SE, can't start conversations from my email address

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

When I'm using iMessages I always prefer they be sent from my email address and not my phone number.  For some reason now however, my phone will not allow me to select my email address to send messages from.  It's available to be selected, but selecting it does nothing.  It just stays on phone number.  How can I set it to use my email address?

I've turned iMessages off & on several times, signed out and back into iCloud... no change.  Running iOS 11.3, iPhone SE 64GB.